# Magento 1 Facebook Pixel Error

Tags: magento-1.9, error, facebook-pixel

I have integrated Facebook Pixel in our Magento 1 Web site. When we check in Facebook Pixel Helper it will show and working fine but in Facebook Pixel Catalogue Manager it will show Error.
See screenshot for more detail.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]